# android - kotlin, custom view, binding, inflating - JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)

Tags: android, kotlin, binding, android-custom-view

**EDIT: Now it is wokrking. Update below...**

Original message:
I am using kotlin.
I am trying create Custom View inside Custom View. I hope, I did it.

Now I would like to change text in my views. I tried use binding.
But when is called: SampleMyViewBBinding.inflate(inflater)
application shows me error:

JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)

I think application trying call inflating again, again, again, ....
Can you help me, what is wrong? How to use binding in Custom View?
Thank you.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

```
class MyViewA : ConstraintLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) { init(null, 0) }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) { init(attrs, 0) }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {  init(attrs, defStyle) }

    private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) {

    }
}
```

```
class MyViewB : ConstraintLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) { init(null, 0) }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) { init(attrs, 0) }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) { init(attrs, defStyle) }

    private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) {
        Log.i("AW", "init test...1")
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        Log.i("AW", "init test...2")
        var binding = SampleMyViewBBinding.inflate(inflater)
        Log.i("AW", "init test...3")
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_Main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text_my_view_MAIN" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_Main">
        <include layout="@layout/sample_my_view_a" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

sample_my_view_a.xml:

```
<com.myapp.mytestingapplication.MyViewA
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/id_MyViewA">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_MyViewA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text_my_view_A" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_MyViewA">
        <include layout="@layout/sample_my_view_b" />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.myapp.mytestingapplication.MyViewA>
```

sample_my_view_b.xml:

```
<com.myapp.mytestingapplication.MyViewB
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_MyViewB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text_my_view_B" />

</com.myapp.mytestingapplication.MyViewB>
```

**EDIT: I change xml and kt files and now it works**
There were wrong using "include" and root element in xml files.

```
class MyViewA : ConstraintLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) { init(null, 0) }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) { init(attrs, 0) }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {  init(attrs, defStyle) }

    private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) {
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_my_view_a, this, true)
    }
}
```

```
class MyViewB  : ConstraintLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) { init(null, 0) }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) { init(attrs, 0) }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) { init(attrs, defStyle) }

    private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) {
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_my_view_b, this, true)

        var t = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_MyViewB)
        t.text = "..text ViewB..."
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_Main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text_my_view_MAIN"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_Main">

        <com.myapp.mytestingapplication.MyViewA
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mva"
            >
        </com.myapp.mytestingapplication.MyViewA>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

sample_my_view_a.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTestingApplication"
    android:id="@+id/id_MyViewA">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_MyViewA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text_my_view_A" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_MyViewA">

        <com.myapp.mytestingapplication.MyViewB
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mvb"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

sample_my_view_b.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTestingApplication"
    android:id="@+id/id_MyViewB">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_MyViewB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text_my_view_B" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed with the constructors and the init block a bit.
You can use `JvmOverloads` to "automatically" generate the constructors for you.
Also, the init block as written below is invoked regardless the constructor being used:

```
class MyViewA @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, 
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null, 
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    init {
        // 
    }
}

class MyViewB @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, 
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null, 
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    init {
        Log.i("AW", "init test...1")
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        Log.i("AW", "init test...2")
        var binding = SampleMyViewBBinding.inflate(inflater)
        Log.i("AW", "init test...3")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it do not help. I had wrong "include" and root element in xml files. Now it is working (I hope). In first message is added working code.